# stream not readable error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, openxml

This code(chunk.feeddata) returns stream not readable error. I dont know why it happens.File has all permissions. Is there any way to resolve it.  All suggestions are welcomed. code simply tries to copy first file to output file and then append next files to the end of output file.

```
public  void Merge()
{  
    try
    {
        string Temps = Server.MapPath(...);    //create folder

        if (!Directory.Exists(Temps))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Temps);
        }

        string output = Path.Combine(Temps + ....+ ".doc");
        string sid = Request.QueryString["id"];
        string stud = sid.ToString();

        string ds = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(......);
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(ds);
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dinfo.GetAccessControl();
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
        dinfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
        if (Directory.Exists(ds))
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(ds);
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*" + stud + "*.docx");


            string[] filepaths = new string[Files.Length];
            int index = 0;

            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                filepaths[index] = file.FullName;
                index++;
            }


            File.Delete(output);
            File.Copy(filepaths[0], output);
            for (int i = 1; i < filepaths.Length; i++)
            {
               using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(output, true))
                {
                    string altChunkId = "AltChunkId1_" + i;
                    MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                    AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId); 

                    FileStream fileStream = File.Open(@filepaths[i], FileMode.Append);
                    {
                        chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
                    } 
                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.AltChunk altChunk = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.AltChunk();
                    altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
                    mainPart.Document
                            .Body
                            .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body
                            .Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>().Last());
                    mainPart.Document.Save();
                   if(fileStream!=null)
                     fileStream.Dispose();
                }


            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at these articles? 
 http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/merge-multiple-word-documents-in-c-sharp-with-same-format

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7582/Merging-Word-Documents-with-C

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileAppending
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            string[] doc1 =             File.ReadAllLines("C:\\FileAppending\\FileAppending\\Doc1.Docx");
        string[] doc2 =     File.ReadAllLines("C:\\FileAppending\\FileAppending\\Doc2.Docx");


               File.WriteAllLines("C:\\FileAppending\\FileAppending\\Doc3.Docx", doc1);
               File.AppendAllLines("C:\\FileAppending\\FileAppending\\Doc3.Docx", doc2);



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mm. I cant use word. and is there any way to set the CanRead property of filestream to true? its false here.

Comment: there isnt a way to set the canRead property to true as it is a read only property. but this value comes from files readonly attribute. write click the file and go to properties to check whether the file is read only or protected.

Comment: when we debug, we cant open that file from specific folder, it says access is denied. only when we debug

Comment: it is because when you debug, you are able to see the exception but when you run the code you havent written any exception handling code. instead of 'using' use try catch block, you will see the exception. I tried some code at my end. but the when i open the new file, it says the file is corrupt.

Comment: thanks for the effort.have a try catch block for the entire function. the exception raising is stream was not readable. that's why i asked about canread property.

Answer (score -1):

I think all files have EOF (end of file) tag at the end of the file. May be this is the reason for not getting appended.

Comment: hi kevalsing. thanks for update. how can we solve that.have any idea?

Comment: Are you getting any error/exception with the current code?

Comment: what is the output? Have you tried using FileMode.Append instead of Open?                                                                                                                                                https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: when using filemode.append, the line chunk.feeddata(filestream) raises exception that stream is not readable

Comment: earlier, with filemode.open the output was just the first file. second file was not appended

Comment: Have you looked at these articles?